# How can I calculate the progressive mean in a vector BUT restarting when a condition is met?

Tags: r, mean

Given the following vector,

```
x<-c(0,0,0,5.0,5.1,5.0,6.5,6.7,6.0,0,0,0,0,3.8,4.0,3.6)
```

I would like to have a vector with the cumulative mean, like

```
cumsum(x)/seq_along(x)
```

but restarting the computation each time that the difference between two subsequent values is grater than 1.3 or less than -1.3. My aim is to obtain a vector like

```
d<-c(0,0,0,5,5.05,5.03,6.5,6.6,6.37,0,0,0,0,3.8,3.9,3.8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum(abs(diff(x)) > 1.3))` to define groups, which are used in `aggregate` to restart `cumsum(x)/seq_along(x)` each time when the difference is grater than 1.3 or less than -1.3.

```
unlist(aggregate(x, list(c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(x)) > 1.3))),
  function(x) cumsum(x)/seq_along(x))[,2])
# [1] 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 5.000000 5.050000 5.033333 6.500000 6.600000
# [9] 6.400000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 3.800000 3.900000 3.800000
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `ave` + `findInterval` like below

```
ave(x,findInterval(seq_along(x),which(abs(diff(x))>1.3)+1),FUN = function(v) cumsum(v)/seq_along(v))
```

which gives

```
 [1] 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 5.000000 5.050000 5.033333 6.500000 6.600000   
 [9] 6.400000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 3.800000 3.900000 3.800000
```